# Mock back-end responses in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-mock

In my application made with Angular 1, I've used angular-mocks to build front-end without requiring the back-end to be up and running:

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myapp')
    .run(['$httpBackend', function($httpBackend) {

      $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*\/api\/ratings\/\?.*/).respond(function(method, url) {
        var params = matchParams(url.split('?')[1]);
        var list = findRatings(ratings, params);
        return createPageResponse(list, params.page, params.size);
      });
    }]
})();
```

Now I want to do that in Angular 2. What is the recommended way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use could use different services depending on some condition:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [..],
  declarations: [..],
  providers: [
    {
       provide: YourService,
       useClass: env.prod ? YourService : DummyService
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [..]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Or with use of a factory, if you need some more complex stuff..

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [..],
  declarations: [..],
  providers: [
    AnotherService,
    {
        provide: YourService,
        useFactory: (isProd, anotherSrvc) => isProd ? new YourService(anotherSrvc) : new DummyService(),
        deps: [env.prod, AnotherService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [..]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```